# List Search Box getting hidden in SharePoint 2013 List View WebPart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to add a list view webpart to my page in sharepoint 2013. I edited the webpart and checked 'Display Search Box' option in the miscellaneous section. But Once I finish editing and save the page, page refreshes and loads. But the search box is not coming at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which occurred since I modified the styles inside the list view.

A few questions...

1. Have you modified the styles inside the view that webpart is using.
2. Is the list a new one or migrated?
3. Is this a Publishing site site or other?
4. You are using enterprise version or other?

Comment: 1) No 2) a new one(even have tried in a new page) 3) publishiing site 4) enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using the Default style , any other style the search box does not appear